# How to restart erl.exe and epmd.exe in rabbitmq?

Tags: windows, erlang, rabbitmq

I accidentally shut down erl.exe and epmd.exe in Rabbitmq.

How can I restart erl.exe and epmd.exe in Rabbitmq then?
I found something like this on the Rabbitmq official site:

[image: [stop command][1].]

Does it mean if I want to restart `erl.exe` and `epmd.exe`, I must reinstall erlang and Rabbitmq service?

By the way, my os is windows.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgyZU.png):

Comment: Did you try to stop and start the service ?

Comment: as I execute rabbitmqctl stop in the command line,I get errors :unable to connect node xxx:nodedown

Comment: no I mean, RabbitMQ service in the Windows Service Manager.

Comment: I tried, it works. Thanks very much.

Comment: welcome, but did it work ?

Comment: yes,it works. the erl.exe is started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart RabbitMQ service in the Windows Service Manager

Comment: epmd.exe still remains and keeps stale environment variables.